# I want to use a declared table name in inner select statement but cant

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    W.AVG_WGHT
    FROM
    ***[LOT] L***                                                       
    INNER JOIN  [DBO].[OWNR_MKUP] MK ON L.[OWNR_INFO_ID= MK.[OWNR_ID]
   ,(SELECT  [AVG_WGHT] 
       FROM [DBO].[DLY_LOT_SUM] DLS
            INNER JOIN [DBO].[LOT] L ON DLS.[LOT_ID] = L.[LOT_ID]
            WHERE DLS.[COST_DTE] = (SELECT MAX(DTE) FROM [DBO].[DLY_HEAD_CNT]  WHERE [LOT_ID] = L.[LOT_ID] AND [CUR_HEAD_CNT] > 0 AND [DTE] <=  @COST_DTE           
   ) W
```

In the inner SELECT statement I have used inner join on LOT L again but I don't want to do that I want to use the LOT L which was previously declared but SQL doesn't allow it to use.

Because of the inner join on LOT L once again I am getting multiple records and I  don't want to use  this inner SELECT statement in upper SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: Skip the sub-qeury, simply join DLS.

Answer (score 1):

You are using both explicit join syntax and implicit (comma separated) join syntax. When you implicitly join your subquery without conditions, you get a cartesian product. Comma separated joins have been replaced by explicit join syntax in ANSI-SQL in 92, the use of comma separated joins is discouraged.

What you probably need is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
           DLS.AVG_WGHT
FROM       [LOT] L                                                       
INNER JOIN [DBO].[OWNR_MKUP] MK 
        ON L.[OWNR_INFO_ID= MK.[OWNR_ID]
INNER JOIN [DBO].[DLY_LOT_SUM] DLS
        ON DLS.[LOT_ID] = L.[LOT_ID]
--WHERE      DLS.[COST_DTE] = [DBO].[DLY_HEAD_CNT] I don't understand this line, what is `[DBO]`?
```

Comment: Sorry Honey there was a slight mistake in the inner SELECT statement the correct one is I have edited it